# Weird whitespace below img inside unordered list

Tags: html, css, image, list

I am trying to make a list with images but I get some weird white space below the pictures.

Here's a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ssxgg32j/1/

CSS:
ul { margin:60px; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
ul li { display:inline-block; margin:0; padding:0; box-shadow:0 0 15px 5px #000; }
ul li img { margin:0; padding:0; }

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225&text=%7B+img+%7D" alt="img 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225&text=%7B+img+%7D" alt="img 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225&text=%7B+img+%7D" alt="img 1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x225&text=%7B+img+%7D" alt="img 1" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add display: block; to the img.

```
ul li img { margin:0; padding:0; display: block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ssxgg32j/2/